# How to check a generic type "T" for Integer in Java?

Tags: java, generics, types

So here's my situation, I have a generic class called:

```
public class SortsTestController<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

Later in the code in order to grab the correct text file, I need to check whether type T is an Integer or a String. I know in C# an easy way to do this is just to do typeOf(T), but to my dismay there seems to be no easy way to do this in Java. Since I'm relatively new to coding, could someone give me a simple work around? Every post I've found mentions type erasure and reflection n' stuff like that and doesn't give a clear solution, and I can barely follow. I just need a simple solution that works.

In case this helps here's what I'm trying to do:

```
if (T is an Integer)
    file += "Int.txt";
else
    file += "Str.txt";
```

Comment: Throws a can't find symbol error, I believe instanceof only works for objects that have actually been instantiated. I've used instanceof on the first element on generic lists, great way to do that in that situation, but it won't work here.

Comment: You would have to use `instanceof` in your generic class...

Comment: I tried doing `Class<T> type` and then assigning it in the constructor. But when I do `type instanceof Integer` it says "incompatiable types Class<T> cannot be converted to Integer.

Comment: ```public class SortsTestController<T extends Comparable<T>>{

    public T myType

    public SortsTestController(T myType) {
        this.myType = myType;
    }

    public String getFileByType() {
        if(myType instanceof Integer) {
            return "Int.txt";
        }
        //remainder of implementation here
    }
} ```

Comment: Do `if (type == Integer.class)` or `if (Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(type))`

Comment: Oh, I really like the first if statement, it all makes sense and works, thanks!